# Save and Update statements no longer work

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, visual-studio-2010

after inserting the much necessary line into my code-

```
    protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      try {


        GridViewRow row = GridView1.SelectedRow; 

            AccountNumber.Text = (string)row.Cells[0].Text;
           .....
            if (DropDownListCurrency.Items.FindByValue(row.Cells[7].Text.ToString().Trim()) != null)
            {
                DropDownListCurrency.SelectedValue = row.Cells[7].Text.ToString().Trim();

            }
      }

      catch (Exception ex)
      {
          Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught.", ex);
      }

    }
```

no errors were thrown and all fields were populated as they should in their corresponding dropdown boxes as well as textboxes. however my save and insert statements no longer work. help!

```
  protected void AgentSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    try
        {

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("XX");
            SqlCommand command = con.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText =
                "Insert into ABC values('" + AccountNumber.Text + "','" + Name.Text + "','" + Address1.Text + "','" + Address2.Text + "', '" + Address3.Text + "','" + PhoneNumber.Text + "','" + FaxNumber.Text + "','" + DropDownListCurrency.Text + "')";
            con.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();  
            con.Close();


            Response.Redirect("main.aspx");

            }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught.", ex);
        }
     }
```

Comment: Be sure to parameterize your sql queries to avoid sql injection attacks: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: they are. they were working fine before i inserted this statement but now they arent..

Comment: please use Parameterized sql queries , they avoid sql injection attacks.please share your full code.

Comment: Can you please fill in `XXX` with some more specific code?  Did you specify the column names?

Comment: are you sure that ur connection string is proper?

Comment: i updated the save statement. please see above. where am i going wrong?

Comment: @Sudhakar - yea. it was working fine - saving/inserting before i inserted the above if statement

Comment: somehw whwn im adding a new record it doesnt even let me click the save button after selecting the currency. it just stops working from there.

Comment: where did you write your if statement , could you please share that too?

Comment: @New2This - You are not disposing of your `SqlConnection` object.  Wrap that in a using statement.  That may be why you are having issues.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey wrap that in a using statement? huh?

Comment: I Think if your Design Elements are not closed properly then this can happen, so please show us your design code(html or aspx) or please check whether DropDownListCurrency element is closed properly. and enclosed elements also closed propelry

Answer (score 0):

*As is this may not be the answer.  Its just getting too difficult to communicate code changes in comments*

You need to dispose of your SqlConnection like so:

```
        using (var con = new SqlConnection("XX"))
        {
            SqlCommand command = con.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = "INSERT ABC VALUES(@AccountNumber, @Name, ";//...you need to fill in all the parameters
            command.Parameters.Add("@AccountNumber", SqlDbType.Text);//Pick proper SqlDbType...whatever it is I dunno
            command.Parameters["@AccountNumber"].Value = AccountNumber.Text;
            //rinse and repeat for rest of params
            con.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();                
        }//using will automatically correctly close and dipose of the connection when con goes out of scope.
```

Comment: its not working. still isnt allowing me to update the value or save a new record with the dropdownlist.

Comment: @New2This - What is the error?  Can you run sql profiler to see if the database is being queried?  Have you tried direct insertion via SSMS?